# Which satisfy the system of inequalities below:

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, integer-lattices

For each nonnegative integer $n$, calculate the number of triples $(a, b, c)$ of nonnegative integers
which satisfy the system of inequalities below:

$ \begin{cases}
a + b \leq 2n \\
a + c \leq 2n \\
c + b \leq 2n \\
\end{cases}$

What I thought: We can solve this by plotting the inequalities with the bounds $x,y,z\geq0$ and getting that all such $(a,b,c)$ are lattice points bounded by the axis and $x+y+z=2n$.

Comment: Unfortunately your approach will miss some triples, such as $(n,n,n)$.

Comment: If you fix $a$, can you find a formula for the number of legal pairs $b,c$? Can you then sum this formula over all $a$?

Comment: The shape produced is a right tetrahedron.

Comment: You must mean non-negative integers, not non-integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constraints define an $n$-fold dilation of the 3-dimensional polytope with vertices $(0,0,0)$, $(1,1,0)$, $(1,0,1)$, and $(0,1,1)$. The number of lattice points is hence a cubic [Ehrhart polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehrhart_polynomial).  By inspection, the counts are $1, 11, 42, 106$, for $n=0,1,2,3$, respectively.  The resulting polynomial is hence
$$2n^3 + \frac{9n^2}{2} + \frac{7n}{2} + 1.$$

Answer (score 0):

Consider the triples $ (a, b, c) $ of nonnegative integers that satisfy the following relationships:
$$\begin{cases} \, a + b = x \\ a + c \leq 2n \\ b + c \leq 2n \end{cases} $$Let's divide the count of these triples into two steps. In the first we consider $ x = 2k $, while in the second we consider $ x = 2k + 1 $.
Thus, the $ (a, b) $ pairs that satisfy $ a + b = 2k $ are $ (2k, 0), ..., (k, k),..., (0.2k) $.

For each of these pairs, $ c $ will have to obey $ c \leq 2n - M $ where $ M = \max (a, b) $, which gives us $ 2n - M + 1 $ solutions.
Assuming that among the $ (a, b) $ pairs that satisfy the equation, the value of $ M $ ranges from $ k + 1 $ to $ 2k $ twice and then goes to $ k $, so the number of solutions for this case it will be:
$$\left(2\sum_{M=k+1}^{2k} (2n-M+1)\right)+ 2n -  k + 1 $$$$= -3k^2+4nk+2n+1 $$For the second case, be $ n = 2k + 1 $. The difference is that we will not have the extra solution in which the components of pair $ (a, b) $ are equal. Like this:
$$\left(2 \sum_{M=k+1}^{2k+1}(2k+1-M+1)\right) $$$$= -3k^2+(4n-3)k+4n $$So just calculate the sum of all cases where $ a + b = 0 $, $ a + b = 1 $,… up to $ a + b = 2n $ and just get the sums for when $ 2k + 1 = 1, 3, 5, \dots, 2n-1 $ and sum with the sums for when $ 2k = 0, 2, 4, \dots, 2n $:
$$\sum_{k=0}^n 3k^2+4nk+2n+1  + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} -3k^2+(4n-3)k+4n $$$$= 2n^3 + \frac{9n^2}{2} + \frac{11n}{2} + 1 $$

Comment: The count for $n=1$ is 11.  Looks like your coefficient of $n$ is wrong.